Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'NextAuth'.ts(2305) import NextAuth
import { NextAuth } from 'next-auth';

in this import statement i got an error

Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'NextAuth'.ts(2305) import
NextAuth

whats the issue i am using   "next-auth": "^4.24.10", this version of nextAuth.

You should do
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

The error was because the "next-auth" package does not have a named export called "NextAuth". Instead, it has a default export which you can name how ever you like but most people just stick to naming it as  "NextAuth"
